# I'm trying to understand how I can search for three different types of strings

Tags: python, string, search, matching

The piece of code below takes a string (userstring) and searches all .txt and .log files in a given directory for a match. However, I've added two other variables (userStrHEX & userStrASCII) where I convert the string to hex and ascii to search all .txt and .log files against these string formats. Currently, these variables are not being used. I'm thinking to add these variables to a list, and maybe use a while loop to iterate through that section of the code up to the number of items in the list. Also, I think I will need to assign each item in the list to a static variable each time the loops is iterated ... I'm stuck! I would appreciate all insight. Thanks!

```
  def do_search(self, line):
          print "  Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
          directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Python27")
          userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
          userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
          userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
          for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
             for file in files:
                 if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                    f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
                    for line in f.readlines():
                       if userstring in line:
                          print "file: " + os.path.join(root,file)           
                          break
                    else:
                       print "String NOT Found!"
                       break
                    f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is probably to create a regular expression that matches all three strings. Take a look at the documentation for the re module. In a nutshell:

```
regex = re.compile( "(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ) )
```

Then instead of "userstring in line", check regex.search( line )

Comment: I had a look, but still not quite sure how re will solve my problem.

Comment: At its simplest, you can think of a regular expression as a way to check if a string is in another string, just like your "userstring in line" check. The equivalent using re is "re.search( userstring, line )". But a regex can do a lot more than check for a literal string. Special characters in the string like +, ., \w, etc. let you check for "one or more", "any character", "any word character". You can also create a regular expression that matches "a" or "b". Try the following:

Comment: Ugh, can't put a newline in here. Things to try from interactive mode: re.search( "a", "foo" ); re.search( "a", "bar" ); re.search( "o|a", "foo" ); re.search( "o|a", "bar" ).